# Why does the sound play faster

Tags: stereo-signal

I am trying to duplicate a stereo channel into four channels.

When I do that the sound plays twice as fast. it's PCM raw data

Basically trying to copy the stereo bytes into four channel buffer.

In Audacity
16kHz plays faster.
8KHz can hear it perfectly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. Could you provide more details? We don't know if you duplicate the channels with your own code, using some software and whatnot.

Comment: Code wise assign channels interleaved

Comment: But its bytes wise so L R L R the channels aren't the channels duplicated

Comment: I see what you mean. Are you modifying the WAV header on your own? Did you update it?

Comment: No it's PCM raw bytes.

Comment: When I open the four channel signal in Audacity I can hear it perfectly in 8kHz, while in 16 kHz its twice the speed, originally it was a 16 kHz stereo

Comment: OK, I rushed a bit with providing you an answer. Would you be so kind and update the question with that information? (i.e. what are the parameters of your input signal, that you achieve conversion by interleaving and what's the output format). 
Also do you have reference for that, i.e. used `sox`?

Comment: Could you try with sox? `sox -b16 -r16k -c2 input.raw out.raw remix 1 2 1 2` 
You might have to adjust: `-b16` is the bit-depth, `-r16k` is the sampling rate.
This should create 4 channel file from a stereo.

Comment: I can't use sox, however I  have used something in the  exact same manner and it's still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120990/discussion-between-jojek-and-gent-binaku).

Answer (score 1):

Let `Sic` be the i-th sample of the c-th channel, you started with stereo (2-channel) 16kHz. Your audio was like this

`s11, s12, s21, s22, s31, s32, s41, s42, s51, s52`

When you made it a 4-channel audio you reassigned the same infromation to different channels like this

`s11, s12, s13, s14, s21, s22, s23, s24`

In the stereo configuration you were using 2 samples every sampling period, so at 16kHz you play 32000 samples per second. With four channel you use 4 samples every sampling period, if you want to play 32000 samples per second your sampling rate needs to be 32000/4, 8kHz.